# Routing between two components in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

Well, this is my `App.vue`:

```
    <template>
  <div id="app">
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
    <Home/>
    <AddService/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Home from './components/Home.vue'
import AddService from './components/AddService.vue'
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/home',
            name: 'home',
            component: Home
        },
         {
            path: '/addService',
            name: 'addService',
            component: AddService
        }
    ]
});
        
Vue.use(router)


export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Home
  }
}
</script>
```

I'd like to route between the Home and AddService Component. My Home page has a link which is basically this:  `<a href="../addService">Add a new Service</a>`

And if I press on this link I should get redirected to the AddService Component. But at the moment it only adds the right url in the search bar but I don't get redirected

Answer (score 1):

When using Vue router you are not supposed to make your own anchor tags with hrefs for navigation. To navigate you can use the [router-link component](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-link).

If you want to programmatically navigate you can use the [push method](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#router-push-location-oncomplete-onabort) on the router.

Answer (score 1):

Your `App.vue` should look like this

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <router-view />
    </div>
</template>
```

Your `index.js` should look like this

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from '@/App.vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Home from '@/components/Home'
import AddService from '@/components/AddService'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'Home',
        component: Home
    },
    {
        path: '/add-service',
        name: 'Add Service',
        component: AddService
    }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes
})


new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

BUT best practise is to use an external router/index.js file to declare all your routes and import to the index.js(main app file) and use it when you declare new Vue instance.

After that you can have `router-link` in your code as

```
<router-link to="path">
```

or navigate programmaticaly with

```
this.$router.push({ name: AddService })
```

or

```
this.$router.push({ path: '/' })
```